# Extending jQuery Form Validation Script for new form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a simple HTML form that originally was a series of Questions (A1 to A5 and B1 to B3) with yes/no radio buttons like this:

```
<tr>
      <td width="88%" valign="top" class="field_name_left">A1</td>
      <td width="12%" valign="top" class="field_data">         
                    <input type="radio" name="CriteriaA1" value="Yes">Yes<input     type="radio" name="CriteriaA1" value="No">No</td>
</tr>
```

The user could only answer either the A series of questions OR either the B series of questions, but not both. Also they must complete all questions in either the A or B series.

I now have an additional series of questions - C1 to C6 - and need to extend my validation scripts to ensure the user enters either A, B or C and answers all questions within each series.

My original script for just the A and B looks like this:

```
    $(function() {

        $("#editRecord").submit(function(){

        // is anything checked?
        if(!checkEmpty()){
            $("#error").html("Please check something before submitting");
            //alert("nothing Checked");
            return false;
        }
        // Only A _OR_ B
        if(isAorB()){
            $("#error").html("Please complete A or B, not both");
            //alert("please complete A or B, not both");
            return false;
        };
        // all A's or all B's
        if(allAorBChecked()){
            $("#error").html("It appears you have not completed all questions");
            //alert("missing data");
            return false;
        };
        if(haveNo()){
            // we're going on, but sending "type = C"
        }
        //alert("all OK");
            return true;
        });
    });


function checkEmpty(){
    var OK = false;
    $(":radio").each(function(){
        if (this.checked){
            OK = true;
        }
    });
    return OK;
}
 function isAorB(){
    var OK = false;
    var Achecked = false;
    var Bchecked = false;
    $(":radio").each(function(){
        var theChar=this.name.charAt(8);
        // if we have an A checked remember it
         if(theChar == "A" && this.checked && !Achecked){
            Achecked = true;    
        }
        if(Achecked && theChar == "B" && !Bchecked){
            if(this.checked){
                Bchecked = true;
            }
        }
        if (Achecked && Bchecked){
            OK = true;
        }
    });
    return OK;
} 
function allAorBChecked(){
    var notOK = false;
    var Achecked = false;
    $(":radio").each(function(){
        // skip through to see if we're doing A's or B's
    var theChar=this.name.charAt(8);
        // check the A's
     if(theChar == "A" && this.checked && !Achecked){
            Achecked = true;    
        }

    });
    if(Achecked){
        // set the input to A
        $("#type").val("A");
        // check _all_ a's are checked
        var thisName;
        var thisChecked = false;

        $(":radio").each(function(){
            var theChar=this.name.charAt(8);
            var checked = this.checked;
            if (theChar == "A"){
            if (this.name == thisName && !thisChecked){
                // Yes wasn't checked - is No?
                if(!checked){
                    notOK = true;
                }
            }
            thisChecked = checked;
            thisName = this.name;
        }
    });
    }else{
        // set the input to B
        $("#type").val("B");            
        // check _all_ b's are checked
            var thisName;
            var thisChecked = false;
            $(":radio").each(function(){
                var theChar=this.name.charAt(8);
                var checked = this.checked;
                if (theChar == "B"){
                if (this.name == thisName && !thisChecked){
                    // A wasn't checked - is B?
                    if(!checked){
                        notOK = true;
                    }
                }
                thisChecked = checked;
                thisName = this.name;
            }
        });
    }
    return notOK;
}    
function haveNo(){
    var thisName;
    var notOK = false;
        $(":radio").each(function(){
            var checked = this.checked;
            if (this.name == thisName){
                //Is this checked 
                if(checked){
                    notOK = true;
                    $("#type").val("C");            
                }

        }
        thisName = this.name;
    });

    return notOK;
}
```

This worked well but I'm completely stuck at extending it to include the C series. I now have to check that the user hasn't answered any A and B, A and C and B and C questions. Everything I've tried fails to validate. Here's where I'm at right now with my new script:

```
    $(function() {

        $("#editRecord").submit(function(){

        // is anything checked?
        if(!checkEmpty()){
            $("#error").html("Please check something before submitting");
            //alert("nothing Checked");
            return false;
        }
        // Only A or B or C
        if(isAorBorC()){
            $("#error").html("Please complete A or B or C, not both");
            //alert("please complete A or B, not both");
            return false;
        };
        // all A's or all B's or all C's
        if(allAorBorCChecked()){
            $("#error").html("It appears you have not completed all questions");
            //alert("missing data");
            return false;
        };
        if(haveNo()){
            // we're going on, but sending "type = C"
        }
        //alert("all OK");
            return true;
        });
    });


function checkEmpty(){
    var OK = false;
    $(":radio").each(function(){
        if (this.checked){
            OK = true;
        }
    });
    return OK;
}
function isAorBorC(){
    var OK = false;
    var Achecked = false;
    var Bchecked = false;
    var Cchecked = false;
    $(":radio").each(function(){
        var theChar=this.name.charAt(8);
        // if we have an A checked remember it
         if(theChar == "A" && this.checked && !Achecked){
            Achecked = true;    
        }
        if(theChar == "B" && this.checked && !Achecked){
            Bchecked = true;    
        }
        if(theChar == "C" && this.checked && !Achecked){
            Cchecked = true;    
        }
        if(Achecked && theChar == "B" && !Bchecked){
            if(this.checked){
                Bchecked = true;
            }
        }
        if(Achecked && theChar == "C" && !Cchecked){
            if(this.checked){
                Cchecked = true;
            }
        }
        if(Bchecked && theChar == "C" && !Cchecked){
            if(this.checked){
                Cchecked = true;
            }
        }
        if (Achecked && Bchecked){
            OK = true;
        }
        if (Achecked && CBchecked){
            OK = true;
        }
        if (Bchecked && Cchecked){
            OK = true;
        }
    });
    return OK;
} 
function allAorBorCChecked(){
    var notOK = false;
    var Achecked = false;
    $(":radio").each(function(){
        // skip through to see if we're doing A's or B's
    var theChar=this.name.charAt(8);
        // check the A's
     if(theChar == "A" && this.checked && !Achecked){
            Achecked = true;    
        }

    });
    if(Achecked){
        // set the input to A
        $("#type").val("A");
        // check _all_ a's are checked
        var thisName;
        var thisChecked = false;

        $(":radio").each(function(){
            var theChar=this.name.charAt(8);
            var checked = this.checked;
            if (theChar == "A"){
            if (this.name == thisName && !thisChecked){
                // Yes wasn't checked - is No?
                if(!checked){
                    notOK = true;
                }
            }
            thisChecked = checked;
            thisName = this.name;
        }
    });
    }elseif{
    // set the input to B
        $("#type").val("B");            
        // check _all_ b's are checked
            var thisName;
            var thisChecked = false;
            $(":radio").each(function(){
                var theChar=this.name.charAt(8);
                var checked = this.checked;
                if (theChar == "B"){
                if (this.name == thisName && !thisChecked){
                    // A wasn't checked - is B?
                    if(!checked){
                        notOK = true;
                    }
                }
                thisChecked = checked;
                thisName = this.name;
            }
        });
    }
    return notOK;
}   

    }else{
        // set the input to C
        $("#type").val("C");            
        // check _all_ c's are checked
            var thisName;
            var thisChecked = false;
            $(":radio").each(function(){
                var theChar=this.name.charAt(8);
                var checked = this.checked;
                if (theChar == "C"){
                if (this.name == thisName && !thisChecked){
                    // A wasn't checked - is B?
                    if(!checked){
                        notOK = true;
                    }
                }
                thisChecked = checked;
                thisName = this.name;
            }
        });
    }
    return notOK;
}   
function haveNo(){
    var thisName;
    var notOK = false;
        $(":radio").each(function(){
            var checked = this.checked;
            if (this.name == thisName){
                //Is this checked 
                if(checked){
                    notOK = true;
                    $("#type").val("C");            
                }

        }
        thisName = this.name;
    });

    return notOK;
}
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there no way just to say "Tick A B or C" and have 1 radio button each for A B and C. You can then use radio button groups using the name attribute? So a user should not be able to select more than 1 radio button in a group, which means you should not need some of the validations above. Only thing then to check would be if a radio button has not been selected in a particular group: `if (!$("input[name^='Criteria']:checked").val()) {
   alert('Nothing is checked!');
}`

Comment: There's more than one question in each group. For example there are 5 yes/no questions for A, 3 questions for B and now 6 for C. The user can answer of these groups:

A1 A2 A3 A4 A5

OR

B1 B2 B3

OR

C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6

Comment: @user982124 What mccannf means is that you shouldn't make the other radio buttons available at all. Make the user first choose whether he wants to answer A, B or C and then give him the corresponding radio button group.

Comment: That part is out of my control. The client would like all possible answers to appear on the screen with instructions to only answer either A, B or C. The user needs to read all the questions to consider which group of questions is the most appropriate. Unfortunately not all users follow the instructions however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think that the best usability would be to make the form easier to use, by making it harder to get wrong. If you are using javascript & jQuery, you may as well set it up so that the user has to pick a section before being able to select any items in it. You can easily support the requirement of showing all the questions, but it is a disservice to the users to allow them to perform needless work (such as filling out more than one section mistakenly) when the computer could very easily prevent this.

If you would like to see what that might look like, please comment and I will work something up for you.

In the meantime, going with your current design, here is [a fiddle demonstrating one possible technique](http://jsfiddle.net/93Ra9/1/). It will work with any number of sections.

Please see that code for a full listing, but here is the script that does the heavy lifting of validation.

```
function validate(ev) {
    var sectionsTouched = $('ol').has(':checked'),
       inputs = {},
       errorMessage = '';

    if (sectionsTouched.length === 0) {
        errorMessage = 'Please check something before submitting.';
    } else if (sectionsTouched.length > 1) {
        errorMessage = 'Please complete only one of sections ' + namesCommaDelimited(seriesNames(), 'or') + '.';
    } else {
        sectionsTouched.find('input').each(function(i, e) {
            var me = $(e), name = me.attr('name');
            inputs[name] = !!inputs[name] || me.is(':checked');
        });
        $.each(inputs, function(k, v) {
            if (!v) {
                errorMessage = 'Please complete all questions in your selected section.';
            }
            return v;
        });            
    }
    if (errorMessage !== '') {
        $('#error').html(errorMessage);
        ev.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Basic logic: if no section has a checked item, display the appropriate message. If more than one section has a checked item, too many sections have answers. If exactly one section has answers, loop through the inputs and collect a list of those that have checks for the corresponding control name. If any name exists that did not have a check, then some control group was left unchecked, and the appropriate message is displayed.

I had to take some liberties to construct a form that suits the requirements well enough for a proper demonstration. Here is what it looks like:

[image: My demonstration fiddle]

I hope this helps!

P.S. For the sake of completeness I would like to mention a couple of style considerations:

- When you find yourself repeating code, try to abstract the repetition away--create a function, or declare a variable. For example, instead of doing `$('#error').html()` multiple times, set a value then do the html-setting only once.
- Try to write code that doesn't secretly depend on document structure such as form field names being in a particular format (having a particular character at a position). Your javascript depends heavily on the `charAt(8)` function returning 'A' or 'B', and this makes it fragile--what if someone else (or even your future self) were to accidentally break the control names? Suddenly the javascript would break and the link between the two is not obvious. You can code it so you don't even need to know which section is which, as long as you have some selector that can indicate each individual section. Using a class name is okay because the class name in javascript obviously has to match the one in the html.

Comment: Thanks for your help here. I'm trying to implement this in my solution which uses tables to display the questions. I've setup a simple fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/fmdataweb/pEETU/5/ which illustrates the format - I'm stuck trying to get it working with a table instead of ordered lists. Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: I can help you in about 5 or so hours... please stay tuned.

Comment: you can use tbody to 'group' sections in a table, i didn't wrote this kind of solution because i didn't want to change much html code much, but this is really elegant solution, if you can go with it.

Comment: @Bart, I am so sorry I didn't get back to you... I totally got wrapped up in life happenings. I was going to find that grouping for table cells and tell you about it. I'm glad you found it! Using `tbody` is exactly the right ticket for separating your question sections from each other, transparent to the user. I do hope that I helped, even if my solution was not the perfect one for you. Do you think you will be using `tbody` elements in order to be able to use something close to my solution?

Comment: @ErikE this ain't my question, i was just adding to the whole. :)

Answer (score 2):

To greatly simplify your task, I'd suggest creating a **single** function that answers, **for a given group**: a) whether anything is checked or not; b) whether everything is checked or not. Something like:

```
function isAnyAllChecked(group) {
    var any = false;
    var all = true;
    $(":radio").each(function(){
        var theChar=this.name.charAt(8);
        if(theChar == group && this.checked){
            any = true;
        }
        if(theChar == group && !this.checked){
            all = false;
        }
    });
    return { any:any, all:all };
}
```

Now your other functions can be trivially rewritten as:

```
function isAorBorC() {
    return (isAnyAllChecked("A").any ? 1 : 0) +
           (isAnyAllChecked("B").any ? 1 : 0) +
           (isAnyAllChecked("C").any ? 1 : 0) !== 1;
}

function allAorBorCChecked() {
    var group = isAnyAllChecked("A").any ? "A" :
                isAnyAllChecked("B").any ? "B" :
                isAnyAllChecked("C").any ? "C" :
                undefined;
    if ( group ) {
        $("#type").val(group);
        return !isAnyAllChecked(group).all;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

Notes:

1. You can reuse the return values of `isAnyAllChecked` for efficiency; I didn't do it in the code above to keep the method interfaces unchanged.
2. You *could* [typecast](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=819) your `boolean` to `int` (implicitly or explicitly) instead of doing `any ? 1 : 0`, but IMHO that way is clearer.
3. You also *could* generalize your solution to an arbitrary number of groups, using arrays and functions like `map`, `filter` etc, but for the small number of groups you have that's not really needed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i think the best approach will be to have 1 form for each section with it's own submit. You only validate if that form got all answered and that's it, the rest is discared.

```
<form id="formA">
<input ...

<button type="submit">Submit with A Answers</button>
</form>
<form id="formB">
<input ...

<button type="submit">Submit with B Answers</button>
</form>
```

etc..

BUT just in case there's a reason for why you are doing that way, here's a fiddle of how it can make it work no matter how many sections, a, b, c, d, e, f etc you have..

> http://jsfiddle.net/cUfY4/

One more thing: there are several ways to resolve this problem.
The proposed Javascript is :

```
$('form').submit(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    var globalAnswers = 0;
    var globalComplete = false;
    $('.section').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this), sectionHasAnswers = false, sectionComplete = true;
        $this.find('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
            var inputName = $(this).attr('name');
            if ($('input[name="' + inputName + '"]').is(':checked')) {
                sectionHasAnswers = true;
            } else {
                sectionComplete = false;
            }
        });
        if (sectionComplete && !globalComplete) {
            globalAnswers++
            globalComplete = true;
        } else {
            if (sectionHasAnswers) {globalAnswers++};
        }
    });

        if (globalAnswers == 1 && globalComplete) {
            // EVERYTHING OK! SUBMIT FORM!
        } else {
            // ERRORS use globalAnswers and globalComplete for exact problem
        }
});
```

Comment: @ErikE even i will iterate over all input, i need to get the selector to get all the 'same-name' input to do the check against is(':checked'). If i do it with individual inputs, i will get for a 2 option answer true / false. while with the selector matching both i will get true / true or false / false, which is what i need.

Comment: @ErikE the globalAnswers is computed outside the foreach. Check the fiddle for the working scenario. also, this: if ($('input[name="' + inputName + '"]').is(':checked')) means, if values of input[name=X] are false, false, returns false, if it's true, true returns true if its false, true returns true. That's the reason why i checking against all inputs of the same name. I will check 2 times if I have 2 options with the same name, but it's fastest than 'filtering' the unique ones, and no worth it the complication on the code.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks. Radio buttons are not a single control, so you can't count the non-checked ones because at least 50% will always be unchecked.